# @RetryableTopic showing weird behaviour when using with topicPartitions to reset offset - spring kafka

Tags: spring-kafka

I am trying to use @RetryableTopic for unblocking retries and topicPartitions in order to read messages from beginning.

Below is my listener (I have only one partition):

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class SingleTopicRetryConsumer {

    @RetryableTopic(
            attempts = "4",
            backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000),
            fixedDelayTopicStrategy = FixedDelayStrategy.SINGLE_TOPIC)
    @KafkaListener(topicPartitions = {@TopicPartition(topic = "products",
            partitionOffsets = @PartitionOffset(partition = "0", initialOffset = "0"))})
    public void listen(ConsumerRecord<String, String> message, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic) {

        log.info("message consumed - \nkey: {} , \nvalue: {}, \ntopic: {}, \nat: {}",
                message.key(),
                message.value(),
                message.topic(),
                LocalDateTime.now());
    }

    @DltHandler
    public void dltListener(ConsumerRecord<String, String> message, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic) {
        log.info("message consumed at DLT - \nkey: {} , \nvalue: {}, \ntopic: {}, \nat: {}",
                message.key(),
                message.value(),
                message.topic(),
                LocalDateTime.now());
    }
}
```

Config properties:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      group-id: group_id
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    producer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

The above code starts to emit weird behaviour, it reads same message twice from main listener and once from DLT but from main topic only.

logs:

```
15:10:50.950 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#8-0-C-1] INFO  c.m.s.c.n.SingleTopicRetryConsumer 
- message consumed - 
key: product1 , 
value: This is Product1, 
topic: products, 
at: 2022-04-07T15:10:50.950810          

15:10:50.950 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#9-retry-0-C-1] INFO  c.m.s.c.n.SingleTopicRetryConsumer - 
message consumed - 
key: product1 , 
value: This is Product1, 
topic: products, 
at: 2022-04-07T15:10:50.950810      

15:10:50.950 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#10-dlt-0-C-1] INFO  c.m.s.c.n.SingleTopicRetryConsumer - 
message consumed at DLT - 
key: product1 , 
value: This is Product1, 
topic: products, 
at: 2022-04-07T15:10:50.950810
```

If I use above code without `topicPartitions` by removing below line, listener works as expected.

```
            partitionOffsets = @PartitionOffset(partition = "0", initialOffset = "0"))}
```

Any clues to why it might be happening ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: This bug has been fixed in Spring for Apache Kafka `2.8.5`.

That's a bug. The problem is we set the retry topic name to the `topics` property of the endpoint, instead of setting it to the `topicPartition`. So we end up with two listeners for the main endpoint and none for the retry topic.

If you can please open an issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues

Not sure there's a workaround for this using topic partitions - it should be fixed in the `2.8.5` release in a couple of weeks.

Thanks for reporting.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @TomazFernandes. I have raised an issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2220

Comment: @AshishSingh, this has been fixed in Spring Kafka `2.8.5`. Thanks again for reporting it.